# Can this mySQL query be faster?

Tags: php, mysql

With this I check if there is already a member registered with the same login. My concern is if the database grows bigger to thousands of members, should I edit this somehow ?

```
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM registered WHERE login='$login'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
```

Comment: Note that "thousands" of members is not a lot for a database.

Answer (score 3):

Just limit the number of columns you're pulling.  Rather than `SELECT *`, just `SELECT login` or something similar.  The query itself won't be slow, as long as `login` is indexed.

```
$qry = "SELECT login FROM registered WHERE login='$login'";
```

Thousands of rows should be no problem at all for the RDBMS. They are designed to handle millions, but you can save a tiny bit of memory by not selecting all columns.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but would `LIMIT 1` make a difference?

Comment: Will this be faster than `count(*)` ?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think limit 1 would make a difference because that affects what rows are fetched. No rows are actually fetched here, we just check the rowcount.

Comment: @servitora it's probably a bit faster than `COUNT()`, but unless you have tens of thousands or more, the difference is likely to be negligible.

Comment: Assuming login is a unique'd field, then there could only ever be one row to retrieve, so adding a limit clause would be pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Few things.

- You should put an index on the row that you are trying to use in your where condition.
- Have you already done escapting? If not your query is vulnerable to injection.
- Even without indexing, 1000 rows is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM registered WHERE login='$login'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($qry));
if($result['cnt']) {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID already in use';
    $errflag = true;
}
else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: @servitora: because it's select only count instead of data

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this won't be any "faster" but you're only returning a single character back to your query if the row exists versus any other field's length.

```
SELECT 1 FROM registered WHERE login='$login' LIMIT 1
```